# AWS Lambda calling SNS

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-lambda, amazon-echo

I'm playing with my Amazon Echo and wrote a little function which I hope would text me after a response from my daughter. The code executes fine - but the sns.publish never happens. It fails silently - I can't raise an error. I believe I have the proper IAM permissions and Topic subscriptions. Can someone help?

```
function textMom(kindOfDay){
    var message = "Test";
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    console.log("textMethod")

    sns.publish({
        TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:",
        Message: message
    }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('error publishing to SNS');
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            console.log('message published to SNS');
            context.done(null, data);
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: What does this print out?

Comment: it will log "textMethod" in CloudWatch but nothing after that. It's like the sns.publish function just silently fails.

Comment: it doesn't print out `message published to SNS`?

Comment: Then it not really failing silently. Are you sure the function call returns and that it's not throwing an exception?

Comment: I don't see an exception. I'm using CloudWatch - the last thing I see is RequestID being returned. How would I see the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and solved by changing publish parameters to below,

```
sns.publish(params, context.done);
```

This help me to check my function is completed before all calls have finished. Try it!

Comment: I wish ... it doesn't work. Have you actually been able to get this to work? Get aws lamdba to publish to a sns topic?

Comment: Yeah, I can invoke Lambda by AWS IoT then sending SNS by Lambda code, did you try removing the "exports.handler", just run your code by "nodejs index.js"? It's more easy to debug in this way.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: Well I did run it through Node and worked out a few permissions issues (because of node). I get the text message immediately. Running the same code through Lambda - no message. Just to be clear - this is an Alexa Skill configuration.

Comment: reference to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/, a Lambda function can complete in one of three ways:
Timeout, Controlled termination, Default termination.

So, if your callbacks have finished in a right way, maybe you can try to increase your lambda function's timeout. (default is 3s, I set to 30s)

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because what I found was that the callback I had was terminating the context before the message was completed. I actually have it working now. Super happy about that. It was driving me crazy!

Comment: Great news! Congratulations!