# Lambda function does not publish to SNS or update dynamodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sns

I am trying to update dynamodb and send SNS notification from Lambda function using the following code. Even though function execute successfully SNS notification does not happen. SNS log does not show any entry either. SNS from console to the same ARN works. Checked to update dynamodb that does not work either. Required IAM role policies for Dynamodb and SNS publish are created. Any pointers or way to debug will help.

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var sns = new AWS.SNS();
AWS.config.update({
region: "us-east-1"
});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
console.log('Received event: ', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
console.log('Received context: ', JSON.stringify(context, null, 2));
// console.log('Cognito id: ', context.identity.cognitoIdentityId);
+console.log("Start .................." + new Date().toString());+
console.log("Notifying....:");
sns.publish({
TargetArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:796915632304:endpoint/GCM/JaybMe/b65794ea-d30d-38a8-8450-e0ff3b877bfc",
Message: "Simple notification message "
}, function(err, data) {
if(err) {
console.error('error publishing to SNS');
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
callback(err);
//context.fail(err);
} else {
console.info('Message published to SNS');
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
callback(null, "SUCCESS");
}
});

console.log('Finished function');
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
callback(null, "SUCCESS");
}
```

Tested with run time 4.3 and 6.10 but same behaviour

thanks
Sajeev

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me of two possible cases;

First, maybe lambda function terminates itself just before sns client finishes sending the message. you better use await or promise() properties of javascript.

Second, maybe you have put your lambda in a VPC. look at a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64295095/2966857).